# delete duplicates on Specific creteria using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have sample data as shown in the image [Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjSvR.png)

I want to delete duplicate entries associated with "VA" in the column "Type" with respect to the date and other records associated  with "DS" & "SD" in the same column should not be processed.

Note: the problem statement requires the solution to be only in VBA code.

Sorry I lost my file with the code, hope the explanation works, I tried using Remove duplicates with the array function but it's removing duplicates for "DS"& "SD" records and I also tried applying a filter and on "VA" and removing duplicates, but I was still unsuccessful.

The output for the problem should look something like as follows

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/171kD.png)

So I would like to seek your help, I am quite new to VBA.

So answer in code is highly appreciated I am quite new to VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It uses an array and a dictionary to select the unique combinations and place their rows in a `Union` range to be deleted at once, at the code end:

```
Sub RemoveDuplicateMoreCond()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, i As Long, rngRem As Range, dict As Object
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row (from A:A)
  
  arr = sh.Range("A1:D" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster processing
  
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'set the necessary dictionary
  For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 4) = "VA" Then
            If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 3) & arr(i, 4)) Then
                dict.Add arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 3) & arr(i, 4), 1
            Else
                addToRange rngRem, sh.Range("A" & i)
            End If
        End If
  Next i
  If Not rngRem Is Nothing Then rngRem.EntireRow.Delete 'delete duplicates at once
End Sub

Sub addToRange(rngU As Range, rng As Range)
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
        Set rngU = rng
    Else
        Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng)
    End If
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it. It should be fast, even for large ranges...

If the range to be processed is really huge, I can adapt the code to use a different way of deletion. When the `Union` range exceeds a specific number of areas, adding to it slows down...

Comment: @Vinay Kumar Please, explain what does "processes other records" mean? It compares columns 1, 3, 4 and eliminates/deletes rows having the same data in the respective columns. Is is anything I am missing? So, If in the fourth column it is not "VA" the other combinations do not count? **Should the code treat only the cases of "VA" in the fourth column**?

Comment: @Vinay Kumar I adapted the above code to process only the cases of "VA" in the fourth column. Does it do what you need now?

Comment: @Vinay Kumar Ups... It should be `arr(i, 4)`. I will correct it now. Corrected.

Comment: @Vinay Kumar But is there anything to be changed? Did you use the initial range not being processed with the previous version? If so, **are you sure that there is ONLY "VA" string in the fourth column**? I mean, without any spaces as prefix or suffix...

Comment: @Vinay Kumar What to **define**? To make the code working even if spaces exists in the fourth column? Or what? You should define an algorithm based on what the code to evaluate that column content...

Comment: @Vinay Kumar Nothing can be tunned to think instead of you, I am afraid... Don't you say to work only for "VA" in the fourth column? What do you mean by that? To be there words starting with "VA"? To be "VA" being prefixed or followed by spaces? I am not a mind reader... If you cannot explain what is to be searched for,  nobody can do it instead of you.

Comment: @Vinay Kumar But this is what the code does! I can also handle different situations, as the ones described above, but **you must be the one telling what is to be processed**...

Comment: @Vinay Kumar What error? Didn't you use the code **as it is**?

Comment: @Vinay Kumar I cannot understand that, but glad I (finally) could help! I would also like to remind/tell you that we here, when somebody answer our question in a convenient way, we tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the supplied answer works...